# C++ templated packs, fold twice

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, fold

I have read some questions that are similar but I don't find the exact thing I am looking for.

In a purely mathematical way a list is defined recursively as: `(head, rest)`.

Where `head` is the first element in the list and `rest` is a list.
So for example (1,2,3,4) is represented as (1, (2,(3,(4,[])))) where `[]` is the empty list.

Then if we want to iterate over the list we can write a recursive function more or less like this:

```
iterate(list)
    head = list.head
    // do stuff and return if head is the empty element
    iterate(list.rest)
```

And if we want to iterate over every 2 elements we do:

```
pair_iterate(list)
        head1 = list.head
        head2 = list.rest.head
        // do stuff and return if head is the empty element
        iterate(list.rest.rest)
```

I am trying to get that second behaviour in C++.

In C++ 17, folds got introduced, so one can do something like this:

```
template<typename...types>
auto sum(types...values) {
  return (... + values);
}
```

But let's say we wanted the sum of the products of adjacent parameters, e.g `sum(1,2,3,4)`
is `1*2 + 3*4`.

In this case we need to "fold twice" to get the the 2 heads to perform the operation and pass the rest of the list. Similar to my pseudocode.

Does anyone have advice on how to get 2 folds in a row?

EDIT:
I specifically want to do it with folds, i.e inside the function declaration without having to rely on recursive templated functions.

Comment: @cigien I don't think that's true. starting state (1,2,3,4). Get the first head off state is (1) (2,3,4), get the second head off state is (1)(2)(3,4) first recursion computes 1 * 2.
Calls itself on the list (3,4). 2 heads pop off and we compute 3 * 4.then we add them together and we get (1*2) + (3*4).

Unless I traced the code wrong.

Comment: No, that's fine, just checking, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the parameters 2 at a time, like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
auto sum_products(T1 t1, T2 t2, Ts ...ts)
{
  return t1 * t2 + sum_products(ts...);
}
```

and provide a base case overload for no arguments:

```
auto sum_products() { return 0; }
```

and then use it like this:

```
std::cout << sum_products(1,2,3,4);  // prints 14
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/tAC4xJ).

Note that this will only work for an even number of arguments, but you can easily add a single argument overload to handle that case.

Comment: Although I really appreciate the answer I should have clarified I want to do it with folds if possible. Your solution is using templated recursion.

Comment: Oh, I see. fold expressions are really just syntactic sugar, but it's fine if that's what you want :) I'll leave this up anyway, and edit if I think of a better solution.

Comment: I am indeed looking for the syntactic sugar to avoid polluting my code with lots of redundant templates. But indeed the answer does solve the technical issue, just not the stylistic issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easier would be to change prototype to take pairs:

```
template <typename ...Pairs>
auto sum_products(Pairs ...ts)
{
    return (... + (ts.first * ts.second));
}
```

else a generic solution is to use `index_sequence`:

```
template <std::size_t... Is, typename T>
auto sum_products_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const T& t)
{
    return (... + (std::get<2 * Is>(t) * std::get<2 * Is + 1>(t)));
}

template <typename ...Ts>
auto sum_products(Ts ...ts)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) % 2 == 0);
    return sum_products_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) / 2>(), std::tie(ts...));
}
```